# .NET twitter library with support of twitter entities

Tags: .net, twitter

Is there any twitter library for .NET which supports twitter entities (http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_entities)?

Best regards,
Alexey Zakharov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Linq2Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) (CodePlex).

Comment: As I know Linq2Twitter has no support of tweet entities.

Answer (score 0):

[Budgie](https://bitbucket.org/mabster/budgie) supports entities. Might be too late for the OP but could help someone else.